# And lead raptivity captive

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, idioms

What do *raptivity* and  ["And lead raptivity captive"](http://www.lycaeum.org/mv/Finnegan/finnegan.cgi?mode=new&simple=boolean&kwor=raptivity&kwnot=&wordmode=fragment&window=2) mean?

Comment: My personal opinion: ["Finnegans Wake"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finnegans_Wake#Language_and_style) questions should be considered off topic on this site.

Comment: In which site would it be on-topic?

Comment: Re: update, a big *no*, that's ungrammatical.

Comment: @RegDwight, I opened a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell, but here's my best analysis. I think *raptivity* is used here as a synonym for *raptness,* an uncommon word meaning *the quality of being [rapt](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rapt).* I can't tell from the text who's speaking or who they're speaking to, but to *lead captive* or *hold captive* mean to hold tightly to something, as though it were your prisoner. Since the line reads:

> And lead raptivity captive. Ready! Like a Finn at a fair.

I guess that the command is intended to provoke a state of attention, readiness, or preparedness. *Like a Finn at a fair* refers to the eagerness or what have you that a person (apparently a Finnish person) would feel at a fair.

Answer (score 2):

@John-Purdy is probably right about the meaning of "raptivity".  "Lead raptivity captive" will be a reference to "lead captivity captive" in [Ephesians 4:8](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=eph%204:8&version=KJV). (And don't ask me what that means - it could be discussed all day if there was a theology stackexchange!)

What it means in the context I have no idea - Finnegans Wake is notoriously complex with strange made up words, grammar, etc. used for artistic effect.  It's the sort of thing most native English speakers would struggle with.